# Nginx how to block IP in specific port

Tags: port, minio

I use nginx as web server and I have use minio port is 9000

```
location = / {
     allow ip_1; 
     allow ip_2; 
     deny  all;
}
```

all coming ip to port 443/80 is allow.
but I want to deny all and allow 2 IP for this port (9000) only ,

Is this possible with nginx?

Comment: Please show your full configuration like `nginx -T` shows.

Comment: please consider to read [the manual](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/)

Comment: I would rather use iptables, but certainly you can use GeoIP or restrict access with nginx 
https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/nginx-whitelisting-certain-ips/
You can also do it on the server section if you just want to block access to the certain port from specific IPs